# Having windows read out what time it is

Tags: time, vbscript

I am using this format to make my computer speak every hour:

```
Dim speaks, speech

speaks = “It is ” & hour(time) & ” O’clock”

Set speech = CreateObject(“sapi.spvoice”)

speech.Speak speaks
```

The problem is it reads it in 24hr and not 12hr format, does anybody happen to know how to fix that? I have my system clock set to 12hr format, but for some reason when its read by Microsoft Hazel, she reads it in 24hr format.

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5dx569a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), `Hour()` returns a number between 0 and 23 representing the current hour. You need to divide the hour modulo 12 to get what you want:

```
speaks = "It is " & Hour(Time) Mod 12 & " o'clock"
```

Comment: how would you make it speak the hour and the minutes?

Comment: By adding the [minutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f41h26kz), obviously.